# .NET visual components

Tags: .net, visual-studio, components

I really like [DevX](http://www.devexpress.com/) components, but they are pretty expensive, maybe anyone knows free equivalents ? or web site where I can look for some kind of free visual component for .NET

Comment: Wait till you see the source and rapidly change you mind.. It's the same case for all the framework components of the kind across the industry and Telerik, Infragistics and SyncFusion are as terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also found that DevExpress offers some [free components](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/WebRegistration/Index.xml).

Answer (score 5):

Check out free [Krypton Toolkit](http://www.componentfactory.com/products.php#toolkit) of Component Factory.

Comment: Your link's broken. The toolkit's at http://www.componentfactory.com/product?id=3

Answer (score 1):

I second that. Krypton all the way. Some of their controls actually outperform the same Telerik control, too.